# Spark Yarn Client Mode access files that are present in the client machine

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark-submit with Yarn and deploy-mode as client, i.e in my client machine my driver process will be opened.I have one text file present in the client machine path and that path is not NFS mount. So can I access this file without loading into any distributed fs or without having the NFS mount.

so will the

```
spark.read.csv("file:/path.txt").show
```

work.

it should be in deploy-mode CLIENT

Comment: It works, did you tried?

Comment: it will work if your file path is NFS mounted. Do you have any pointer for the official documentation for this. will it work for any client local path that is not enabled for NFS protocol.

Comment: Chandan the protocol is file:// to access local storage and I believe that might be the cause of issue in your cause. When running on client deploy-mode you can access files on the local machine.

Comment: @MansoorBabaShaik I tried that and if the path is NFS mounted I am able to access but other path like home folder in my client machine I am not.Could you please check once from your side.

Comment: @ChandanRay I believe you should pass that file via --files and then access via file:// internally from your code. Could you try this and provide the error log.

Comment: @MansoorBabaShaik I suppose --files will copy the files to all executor and if you are running in CLUSTER mode then it will work. Is it the same for CLIENT mode I doubt